# Parsing results of additional requests in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape lynda.com courses and storing their info in a csv file. This is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import itertools


class LyndadevSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lyndadev'
    allowed_domains = ['lynda.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lynda.com/Developer-training-tutorials']

    def parse(self, response):
        #print(response.url)
        titles = response.xpath('//li[@role="presentation"]//h3/text()').extract()
        descs = response.xpath('//li[@role="presentation"]//div[@class="meta-description hidden-xs dot-ellipsis dot-resize-update"]/text()').extract()
        links = response.xpath('//li[@role="presentation"]/div/div/div[@class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 card-meta-data"]/a/@href').extract()

        for title, desc, link in itertools.izip(titles, descs, links):
            #print link
            categ = scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse2)
            yield {'desc': link, 'category': categ}

    def parse2(self, response):
        #getting categories by storing the navigation info
        item = response.xpath('//ol[@role="navigation"]').extract()
        return item
```

What I am trying to do here is that I am grabbing the titles, description of the list of tutorials and then navigating to the url and grabbing the categories in parse2.

However, I get results like this:

```
category,desc
<GET https://www.lynda.com/SVN-Subversion-tutorials/SVN-Java-Developers/552873-2.html>,https://www.lynda.com/SVN-Subversion-tutorials/SVN-Java-Developers/552873-2.html
<GET https://www.lynda.com/Java-tutorials/WebSocket-Programming-Java-EE/574694-2.html>,https://www.lynda.com/Java-tutorials/WebSocket-Programming-Java-EE/574694-2.html
<GET https://www.lynda.com/GameMaker-tutorials/Building-Physics-Based-Platformer-GameMaker-Studio-Using-GML/598780-2.html>,https://www.lynda.com/GameMaker-tutorials/Building-Physics-Based-Platformer-GameMaker-Studio-Using-GML/598780-2.html
```

How do I access the information that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `yield` a `scrapy.Request` in the `parse` method that parses the responses of `start_urls` (instead of yielding a dict). Also, I would rather loop over course items and extract the information for each course item separately.

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by categories. I suppose those are the tags you can see on the course details page at the bottom under *Skills covered in this course*. But I might be wrong.

Try this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class LyndaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lynda"
    allowed_domains = ["lynda.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.lynda.com/Developer-training-tutorials']

    def parse(self, response):
        courses = response.css('ul#category-courses div.card-meta-data')
        for course in courses:
            item = {
                'title': course.css('h3::text').extract_first(),
                'desc': course.css('div.meta-description::text').extract_first(),
                'link': course.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
            }
            request = scrapy.Request(item['link'], callback=self.parse_course)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_course(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        #item['categories'] = response.css('div.tags a em::text').extract()
        item['category'] = response.css('ol.breadcrumb li:last-child a span::text').extract_first()
        return item
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer, If you click on any course. You will see at the top left

Comment: You mean the breadcrumb navigation? I've edited the answer to reflect your specification - it now extracts the text from the last navigation item.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it anyway. You were a lifesaver. BTW, would you know how to do a 2stage login?